# NameError uninitialized constant JobsController::Pagination using no gems in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module, pagination

Using Rails 6.1.6 and Rails 2.7.0. and am following an article for adding pagination in Ruby using no gems. I'm running into a NameError exception for my Pagination module. Not certain if the naming of the hierarchy in the module is incorrect.

**Pagination Helper**

```
module PaginationHelper
  def paginate(collection:, params: {})
    pagination = Services::Pagination.new(collection, params)

    [
      pagination.metadata,
      pagination.results
    ]
  end
end
```

**Jobs Controller**

```
class JobsController < ApplicationController

  include Pagination

  JOBS_PER_PAGE = 8

  def index
    @pagination, @jobs = paginate(collection: Job.all, params: page_params)
  end
```

**Error Message**
[NameError Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGjJN.jpg)

I've tried restarting the server to no avail. Am I missing something in the Pagination module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should be `include PaginationHelper` in your controller.

Or rename the helper to `module Pagination`.

Comment: Right on! That did it. Now I know I need to match the module name with the dependency.